# XSLT sum is concatenated instead or summed

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Here is a snippet of some XSLT code.

It is outputting the results concatenated instead of summed.  For example it will find the following matches: `100` and `200` and will output `12002400`.  Which is `100 * 12` and `200 * 12` concatenated.  I need the output in `XMLField1` to be `3600`.

Can someone point me in the right direction and help explain what we are doing wrong?  I'm not an XSLT expert.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="Root">
    <XMLField1>
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select="Row[contains(BenefitType, 'MyBenefit')]" />
    </XMLField1>


  <xsl:template match="Row[contains(BenefitType, 'MyBenefit')]">
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(BenefitList/Premium) * 12" />
  </xsl:template>
```

I am looking for an *XSLT 1.0* compliant solution.

Comment: Could we see an example of the XML input?

Comment: I added some more details to the answer to this question. Since you are making several questions using the same structures, please refer to your previous questions when posting new ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second template is performing calculations separately, but your aren't using that for anything. You *don't need the second template* if you just want the sum of all `Premium` nodes in rows that contain `MyBenefit`:

```
<xsl:template match="Root">
    <XMLField1>
        <xsl:value-of
            select="sum(Row[contains(BenefitType, 'MyBenefit')]/BenefitList/Premium) * 12" />
    </XMLField1>
</xsl:template>
```

This would produce:

```
<XMLField1>3600</XMLField1>
```

**UPDATE:**

You didn't post your source XML. I'm *assuming* it has a structure that resembles this:

```
<Root>
    <Row>
        <BenefitType>MyBenefit</BenefitType>
        <BenefitList>
            <Premium>100</Premium>
        </BenefitList>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <BenefitType>MyBenefit, OtherBenefit</BenefitType>
        <BenefitList>
            <Premium>100</Premium>
        </BenefitList>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <BenefitType>OtherBenefit</BenefitType>
        <BenefitList>
            <Premium>1000</Premium>
        </BenefitList>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <BenefitType>OtherBenefit</BenefitType>
        <BenefitList>
            <Premium>1000</Premium>
        </BenefitList>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <BenefitType>MyBenefitSpecial</BenefitType>
        <BenefitList>
            <Premium>100</Premium>
        </BenefitList>
    </Row>
</Root>
```

Since you are using `contains()` it's important to be aware that it will match strings that *contain* `MyBenefit` (including `MyBenefit, OtherBenefit`, `MyBenefitSpecial`)

Here is an online working example: http://xsltransform.net/bFukv8t/1

---

If you created a second template because you wanted *separate* results for each row, then you just have to add something in the template. A tag perhaps:

```
<xsl:template match="Row[contains(BenefitType, 'MyBenefit')]">
    <subtotal>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(BenefitList/Premium) * 12" />
    </subtotal>
</xsl:template>
```

which would produce for the sample input I provided above:

```
<XMLField1>
    <subtotal>1200</subtotal>
    <subtotal>1200</subtotal>
    <subtotal>1200</subtotal>
</XMLField1>
```

You can have both the sum and this result if you change your *other* template:

```
<xsl:template match="Root">
    <XMLField1>
        <total><xsl:value-of
            select="sum(Row[contains(BenefitType, 'MyBenefit')]/BenefitList/Premium) * 12" />
        </total>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Row[contains(BenefitType, 'MyBenefit')]"/>
    </XMLField1>
</xsl:template>
```

Now you will get:

```
<XMLField1>
   <total>3600</total>
   <subtotal>1200</subtotal>
   <subtotal>1200</subtotal>
   <subtotal>1200</subtotal>
</XMLField1>
```

Hopefully you can apply these examples to your real case scenario and obtain the results you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks.  I will do my best and get back to you with any questions.

Comment: The problem I ran into is that when I do this select="sum(Row[contains(BenefitType, 'MyBenefit')]/BenefitList/Premium) * 12" />, I only get the first occurence.  It doesn't sum together all occurances.  I assume maybe it's a problem with contains?

Comment: When you get convert a node-set to its string value only the first node will be converted. But that's not the case here, since `contains` is being used in the predicate to select a result, and `sum()` is actually receiving a node-set. Perhaps you can try to reproduce your problem here: http://xsltransform.net/bFukv8t/1

Comment: Everything is now working.  Your response was amazing and incredibly helpful!  Thanks!